Given $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $Y=\{1,2,3,...,15\}$. Find number of injective functions $f:X\to Y$ such that $f(i)>i$ for all $i\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$..
Given $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $Y=\{1,2,3,...,15\}$. Find the  number of injective functions $f:X\to Y$ such that $f(i)>i$ for all $i\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$.
My Attempt:
For $f(1)$ we have $14$ choices.
For $f(2)$ we have either $13$ choices if $f(1)=2$ or we have $12$ choices if $f(1)\neq 2$ so in all for $f(2)$ we have $25$ choices.
But for $f(3)$ it is becoming quite confusing.
I am trying to create a recursion situation here.
If $X=\{1,2,3,...,m\}$ and $Y=\{1,2,3,...,m+k\}$.
Then let $a_m$ be number of such functions where $f(i)>i$.
Let us introduce the element $m+1$ in $X$.
How can I express $a_{m+1}$ in terms of $a_m,a_{m-1},..$
Derangement would have worked if $k$ had been equal to $0$

Why does your counting for $f (2)$ depend on the value you picked for $f (1)$?

Functions don't have to be injective. Just multiply.

If you are requiring injectivity, you need to specify that.

If you want injectivity (which, again, was never stated) then it is easier to work from the other end.  There are $10$ possible values for $f(5)$ and, then, having fixed that value, there are $10$ possible values for $f(4)$ (as you acquire $5$ as an option, but lose $f(5)$).  And so on.  If you don't really want injectivty, then it is easier.

My sincere apologies.Injectivity is required. I have edited.

To summarize the discussion in the comments:
There are $10$ options for $f(5)$.  Having fixed that value, there are now $10$ options for $f(4)$, as you acquire $5$ as an option but lose $f(5)$.  This pattern continues and, in the end you have $\boxed {10^5}$ possible injective functions which pass your requirement.
Without the injectivity requirement:  There are $14$ options for $f(1)$, $13$ for $f(2)$ and so on, making the total  number equal to $$\frac {14!}{9!}=240240$$

Just for interest "How many injective functions $f:X\to Y$ would be possible if $f(i)\neq i$"

For that one, I'd use Inclusion-Exclusion as in one of the standard ways to count derangements.  For any specified subset of the domain, it is easy to count the injective functions which fix that subset.
